# Are all PHP equality comparisons symmetric?

Tags: php, comparison, equals-operator

Is `$a == $b` always equivalent to `$b == $a`?

I think in JavaScript there are a few weird cases where that's not true, due to casting.

I think [ide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752579/are-all-php-equality-comparisons-symmetric#comment5256224_4752579) is correct. I'll ask another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753759/is-the-operator-transitive-in-php).

Comment: I would say 'reflexive'.

Comment: @Joe is correct. This is considered _reflexivity_. Associativity is when `(A + B) + C = A + (B + C)`

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but I think the weird cases arise for transitivity; i.e., `a == b` and `b == c` but `a != c`.

Comment: I have tried a number of variations and cannot find a case where `($a == $b) !== ($b == $a)`, but I am determined to do so now!

Comment: @ide: Oh... is that where it occurs? Maybe I should have asked that instead then :)

Comment: This is NOT reflexivity - this is symmetry! Reflexivity is where `$a == $a`!

Comment: As far as reflexivity is considered, there is `NAN != NAN` but that might be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends what happens between those two calls. Otherwise yes, those are the same. The order makes no difference. Using 2 equals `==` A string of 1 and integer of 1, will return true when compared.  Type is ignored, only value is compared.  So no wierdness.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

```
<?

$a=(string) 1;
$b=(int) 1;

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);


echo $a==$b;
```

Outputs: 1

http://www.ideone.com/JLJWQ

**EDIT**

To clarify, there is absolutely nothing you can ever put in $a or $b to get a different output on the comparison, just by putting it on the other side of the operator.

```
$a="1234";
$b="1234";

echo $a==$b;
echo $b==$a;
```

The output of that, for any $a or $b values, will always without a doubt be true true, or false false.

Comment: Yeah, but that's a simple example. I thought maybe there were some strange cases like `"01" == 1` the 1 might get converted to a string and then they'd not be equal, but in `1 == "01"` the string would get converted to an int, and then they would be equal. I know this isn't the case though. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion But maybe there's some weird ones I don't know about.

Comment: well.. there is one kinda weird one that is mentioned in the comments. Its with numeric strings. But it is as expected. Even in this though, the side of the operator each is on, will not matter. http://www.ideone.com/UHD43

Comment: Yeah...that's weird, but at least it's documented. Accepting this answer for being definitive.

Answer (score 4):

In short, yes. `$a == $b` will always be the equivalent of `$b == $a`. There are some short comings, such as floats. Of course, you shouldn't be nesting two float for equality anyways.

**EDIT**
Concerning floats: If you had two float and compared them, they technically should be the same. However, floating point values which seem to have the same value do not need to actually be identical. So, if `$a` is a literal `.69` and `$b` is the result of a calculation, they can very well be different, but both display the same value. This is why you should never compare floating-point values by using the `==`.

If you need to compare floating-point values, you really need to use the smallest acceptable difference in your specific case. Something like this would work for comparing floats (setting our smallest acceptable difference at `0.000001`):

```
if(abs($a-$b) < 0.000001) {
  //Same
}
```

[PHP: abs - Absolute Value](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php)

Comment: Can you give an example of where the floats would compare equal one way, but not the other? I understand the rounding errors due to floats, but shouldn't it be consistently compared in either direction?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include some more information on float comparisons. I hope it helps.

Comment: No it doesn't :) That's a bit unrelated. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3):

The only type that I could see being different is something like:

```
$foo = 1;
$bar = 1;

($foo = $foo + $bar) == ($bar = $foo);
```

To see why, look at it

```
A -> ($foo = $foo + $bar)
B -> ($bar = $foo);
```

If `A` is run first, the result will be `2` and the result of `B` will be 2, so they are equal and the test will be `true`.

If `B` is run first, the result will be `1`, and the result of `B` will be 2, so they are not equal and the test will be `false`.

But for any single type comparison (Where `A` is a variable and not an expression) it will always be reflexive.

So in the general sense, `A == B` is not always 100% guaranteed to be equivalent to `B == A`.  For variables, it will always be equivalent.  But for complex expressions involving assignment or modification of variables it may not be.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

There are diffrent operators you can use if you want to consider type casting in the comparison.  `==` evaluates as true on equal value, but does not compare data type. `===` evaluates as true when values are equal as well as datatypes.  Using the latter considers type casting where it would normally be ignored (eg: string that represents an integer and an integer being compared.)

The order of the logic in the conditional should not make a difference.

Comment: I don't like your use of the word "should". Was hoping for a definitive answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried a number of variations and cannot find a case where `($a == $b) !== ($b == $a)` but none so far have worked:

```
<?php

$a = 0;
$b = "0";

echo (($a == $b) == ($b == $a)) ? "OK\n" : "FAIL\n";

$a = 0;
$b = NULL;

echo (($a == $b) == ($b == $a)) ? "OK\n" : "FAIL\n";

$a = 0;
$b = false;

echo (($a == $b) == ($b == $a)) ? "OK\n" : "FAIL\n";

$a = false;
$b = NULL;

echo (($a == $b) == ($b == $a)) ? "OK\n" : "FAIL\n";

$a = "";
$b = NULL;

echo (($a == $b) == ($b == $a)) ? "OK\n" : "FAIL\n";

$a = "NULL";
$b = NULL;

echo (($a == $b) == ($b == $a)) ? "OK\n" : "FAIL\n";

$a = 0.000000000000000000000000001;
$b = 0;

echo (($a == $b) == ($b == $a)) ? "OK\n" : "FAIL\n";

$a = array();
$b = array();

echo (($a == $b) == ($b == $a)) ? "OK\n" : "FAIL\n";
```

So, I give up at this point. Ideas welcome!