# Is the == operator transitive in PHP?

Tags: php, equality

In JavaScript, the `==` operator isn't necessarily transitive:

```
js> '0' == 0
true
js> 0 == ''
true
js> '0' == ''
false
```

Is the same true in PHP? Can you give an example?

Comment: http://se2.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: The same samples can be run in the php with the same results.

Comment: @zerkms: All of em? Strings, and ints, and all that weirdness yield the same result? Not just this one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are all PHP equality comparisons reflexive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752579/are-all-php-equality-comparisons-reflexive)

Comment: Err.. sorry... voted to close since it seemed to me as a duplicate of you previous question, but that one was aobut reflexivity of the operator.

Comment: @Mchl: Yeah... I specifically asked this question *because* I think this is where the weirdness occurs, not with reflexivity.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**No**, the `==` operator is not transitive.

The exact same scenario gives the same result in PHP.

```
echo var_dump('0'==0);
echo var_dump(0=='');
echo var_dump('0'=='');
```

yields:

```
boolean true
boolean true
boolean false
```

Comment: Yup.  The reason for this is because the right operand is typecast into the data type of the left operand.  `0` typecast to a string becomes `'0'`, `''` typecast to an int becomes `0`, but `''` is already a string, so it is directly compared to `'0'` and found not equal.  Though the exact reasons in javascript are a little different.

Comment: -1 Why are you answering your own question? (If you knew the answer, why ask it?) No offence, but with a rep of >10K you should really know better and "show and tell" questions aren't really acceptable.

Comment: @middaparka: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions I'm not trying to farm rep. I didn't know the answer *before* asking the question, just very shortly after I decided to actually test it. And just because *I* easily figured out the answer, doesn't mean everyone else is aware of this transitivity problem. What's so awful about educating the community and saving them from having to run this code?

Comment: @Gordon: No. It is an answer. I was hoping other people would post other examples too.

Comment: @keithjgrant: But in `'01' == '1'` *both* operands are converted to ints, even though they're already the same type. So in `'0'==''`, `'0'` remains a string because the other operand can't be converted to an int as well?

Comment: @Mark Apologies. (I've removed my downvote - had to "edit" your question, but made no changes whatsoever.) However, for a question that's so trivial to answer (it took you all of two minutes), it still feels a bit cheap.

Comment: @middaparka: Like I said, I don't really care about the rep. I didn't know this before posting it, so maybe someone else will learn something too, even if it is trivial to figure out on your own, it's not something you would usually expect or think about.

Comment: So the answer is no, the == operator is not transitive in php?

Comment: @Mark: typecasting is one of the most important aspects of PHP (and JavaScript). You should *always* be aware of it.

Comment: @Roger: Correct. I should have included that. I like answers that spell it out, even if it's implied in the paragraph. @webbiedave: Yeah... for `'0'==0` it's simple, but when you add a 3rd variable, it's less obvious. The conversion isn't performed the same. In general, if a==b==c, you'd expect a==c.

Comment: @mark: Interesting.  You're right.  This sort of thing is exactly why I use the `===` operator for comparison in PHP, whenever possible.

Comment: Note that neither are `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` transitive. For example: `0 < '1'` and `'1' < 'a'` are both true, but `0 < 'a'` is false.

Answer (score 2):

The same is true in PHP:

```
//php

'0'==0  //true
0==''   //true
''=='0' //false
```

Did you not test it yourself? These are the same statements you provided for javascript.

Comment: Yes, I did. A second after posting it. See my answer. Was a spin-off of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752579/are-all-php-equality-comparisons-reflexive Asked it for completeness and to make other SO-ers aware... it's not really intuitive.

Comment: @Mark: Cool. +1'd your answer, there's nothing wrong with doing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
array() == NULL // true
0 == NULL       // true
array() == 0    // false
```

The problem with scripting languages is that we start comparing things in a non-strict way, which leads to different senses of "equality." when you are comparing "0" and 0, you mean something different then when you are comparing "0" and NULL. Thus it makes sense that these operators would not be transitive. Reflexivity however, should be an invariant. Equality is by definition reflexive. No matter what sense you mean equality, it should always be true that A equals itself.

another more obvious one:

```
true == 1 // true
true == 2 // true
1 == 2    // false
```

Comment: `0 == null` evaluates to `true` for me.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I tested with `===` for the last one without realising it. Here is an alternate

Comment: "makes sense that these operators would not be transitive" -- only if you tilt your head and look at it in a weird sort of way. None of your examples make any sense to me; I think they should return `null` instead or error out. In your last sentence, do you mean if `A == B` entails `B == A`? But if PHP can break other laws of logic, it really wouldn't surprise me if that didn't always hold true either.

Comment: I think the problem here is that it's called "equality" when really it means something more like "is kinda similar to". Then if A is "kinda similar" to B, and B is "kinda similar" to C, it does *not* follow that A is "kinda similar" to C (if it doesn't meet the threshold for similarity).

Comment: well yeah... that's exactly it, `==` totally means "is kind of similar to". that's because it's a scripting language - these "equalities" are there for convenience. PHP at least provides you with `===` for strict equality. and no, i did not mean `A == B` => `B == A`, that is symmetry, not reflexivity. in other scripting languages, the `==` operator simply uses the .equals() method, which means you can make it mean whatever you want. for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185879/powershell-equality-operator-not-a-symmetric-relation

Comment: Yeah... I like that example better. I guess `A == A` seems too obvious to mention until you consider overloading the operator.

Comment: yeah, i mostly mentioned it because you mentioned reflexivity in your other question.