# PowerShell equality operator not a symmetric relation?

Tags: powershell

Can someone please explain to me why the equality operator in PowerShell is not a symmetric relation??

```
PS> "" -eq 0
False
PS> 0 -eq ""
True
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `-eq` in PowerShell is not an equivalence relation. While theorists may cry out in terror at this point it's mostly to make the language better at conveying ideas and simpler to understand.

For example, PowerShell *always* tries converting differing types in binary operators to the type of the *left* operand which is why you see the behaviour in your question. In practice I have found this to be rarely a problem, except in contrived examples. In my own data I usually write comparisons with matching types and when working with other data the conversions are *usually* not harmful in that they detroy the meaning. And this is a case where I think *predictability* of the language is more important than attaining a mathematical ideal (which isn't even attainable everywhere anyway given that numbers in computers are only approximations of mathematical entities).

Another thing is that if the left operand of a comparison operator (`-eq`, `-gt`, `-lt`, `-ge`, `-le`, `-match`, ...) is a collection, then the operator returns all items of the collection where the operator would yield true. This would be a case where you can quickly filter a collection without needing a `where`, *but* I guess the real advantage is that you can write the conditional `if ($foo -gt 4)` which then can mean both »if `$foo` is a scalar value larger than 4« or »if `$foo` is a collection containing items larger than 4« without needing to stick a pipeline into the `if`.

Comment: i disagree that it makes the language better at conveying ideas, or simpler to understand. an equality operator should convey equality.

if the .Equals method is what was wanted, that is still available.

Comment: Nacht, ask fellow developers if they even know what an equivalence relation is. `-eq` works as expected in the vast majority of cases and has a few tweaks that make some cases simpler. What your question pointed out was a choice of how PowerShell converts operands, though and has nothing to to with `-eq` per se. It works the same for `+` or `-lt`. And the way that it works *predictably* is in my eyes much more important than how exactly it operates.

Comment: PowerShell is all about learning concepts once and reusing them. Having complex rules for how exactly and in what cases operands are converted from and to what types just makes things confusing. Compare with PHP for an example where `==` always converts operands to numbers if possible even if they are strings that just happen to contain digits.

Comment: shouldn't it, as an operator, convert both operands to [bool] first, and then compare them? that seems almost as simple to me, and would avoid massive confusion, as I have recently experienced.

it's not as if all operators have their operands converted to be the same type before the operation can occur - since some operators require their operands to be of different types, e.g. -contains.

Comment: Yes, some operators operate differently since they don't work on all types. `-contains` doesn't do a conversion upfront, though; the result looks more like `-eq` being applied to individual items (e.g. `'3',1,2 -contains 3` – what would you convert `3` to?). `-split` will convert its arguments to `string`, `-match` and `-replace` to `[regex]` and `string` and so on. But all those are explainable by common sense and don't have the particular problem of the universal binary operators that can be overridden too so type conversion is less problematic with the special-purpose operators.

Comment: Oh just saw your edit... I happen to consider myself as one of those theorists, but I can see it's certainly not as clean cut as I was thinking... though I would say that the pure mathematical ideal is by definition the most predictable. and as to whether or not it's attainable... if we can think it in our heads procedurally, then a computer can too... though that's a lots more philosophical than the scope of this question allows :P

Comment: Well, few data types in computers (probably none apart from booleans and bignums) follow mathematics and each have their own quirks (e.g. wraparound (ok, that's just a field mod 2^x, I think), infinities in the same set with numbers, unevenly-spaced real numbers, ...). So operators break down there too in that things like `x+y >= x` can be false even it both `x` and `y` are non-negative. It's a messy world and we have to make do ;-). In this case the language designers were not utter morons by deviating in a different direction, though. At least in my humble opinion ;-)

Comment: Note that .Equals() does identity rather than equivalence comparison, and for NaNs it DOES NOT do IEEE754 NaN comparison, so $nan -eq $nan returns True in powershell. In C# == does IEEE equivalence comparison and .Equals() does identity comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It is how PowerShell tries to convert the type and then compare.

Check this:

```
$false -eq ""
```

This returns True as well.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that in the first case, there is a conversion of the right hand operand from 0 to "0" (the type of the left hand operator being a string), therefore "" is not equal to "0". In the second case, there is a conversion from "" to int, and "" is considered as being 0.

Try 3 + ""

Answer (score 0):

When you do `"" -eq 0`, it is same as `"".equals(0)` and it returns false.

`0 -eq ""` will try to convert `""` to in and `[int]""` is 0 and hence you get true.

Comment: `"" -eq 0` would convert `0` to `"0"` first, I think.

Comment: if this is the case, then how come `$false -eq [bool]$null` returns `True` and `$false -eq $null` returns `False`?