# Is either use of the equals sign '=' in R a symmetric relation?

Tags: r, parameter-passing, variable-assignment, relation, assignment-operator

I am aware of at least two distinct uses of the equals sign in the R-programming language:

(1) as a deprecated assignment operator, i.e. `x = 3` instead of `x <- 3`.
(2) for passing values of arguments to functions, e.g. `ggplot(df, aes(x = length, y = width))`

Do either of these operators correspond to symmetric relations ([in the sense of mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_relation))?

The 'equals' operator == does (I think), which is why it corresponds most closely to the use of the equals sign in mathematics (which is always a symmetric relation).

But for example if one tried to run `ggplot(df, aes(length = x, width = y)` one would get an error, and one would also get an error trying to run `3 = x`.

Thus, is it true that, unlike in mathematics, the equals sign in R is *not* a symmetric relation? Is that why `<-` is preferred by some for assignment, because it better conveys the lack of symmetry?

**Bonus question:** are there other programming languages where the equals sign does not correspond to a symmetric relation? PowerShell (I have never heard of it before) [might be one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185879/powershell-equality-operator-not-a-symmetric-relation).

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call = "deprecated" as an assignment op, although many people prefer <-

Comment: And tons of languages use = as assignment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `=` operator is not symmetric in R. When it comes to assignment, `=` is basically a function that takes a symbol and a value and assigns that value to that symbol. When it comes to named parameters, it's really just part of the syntax of naming a parameter.

`<-` is preferred for assignment simply because it has an unambiguous meaning.